# Selenium. Можно ли передать сохраненные пароли от сайта в chrome?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, test-automation

При поднятии нового экземпляра chromedriver, хотелось бы прокинуть для конкретного сайта креденшелы, чтобы при открытии сайта можно было воспользоваться автозаполеннием. Ничего полезного не нашел, кроме как создать профиль с сохраненными данными, но проблема в том, что тесты запускаются всегда с новой парой логин/пароль. Может есть у кого идея или уже решение было похожее?

Comment: Или не юзать автозаполнение, а вводить через set, send_keys, или как оно там называется в вашей питоновой либе, или сделать так на сервере, чтоб пароль был всегда одинаков.

Comment: Да, так и есть, пароль для всех юзеров один, и все тесты на ввод данных работают, но есть тест связанный с проверкой именно сохраненной пары логин/пароль

Comment: Попробуй такую схему. 1 итерция - копируем профиль, открываем новый хром и туда сохраняем пароль. 2 итерация - перезапускаем хром и 
 тестируем автозаполнение

Comment: Александр, если вы тестируете сайт, то это не должно входить в ваши тесты. Автозаполнение (подтягивание сохраненных из файлов сессии) паролей -- это дело браузера, и функционал этот тестируется не вами, а разработчиками браузера -- Microsoft, Google, Yandex, Mozilla.

Comment: @Nakilon я прекрасно понимаю, что это функционал браузера) и тестируют его разработчики, но потребность есть и ее нужно удовлетворить)) по этому думаю все же выполнить задачу с использованием профиля